# How can I retrieve the column names from an empty MySQL select query result

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to retrieve the column names of a query that returns no data?
The result of this query would be empty. 
Is there a way how to find the column names when there's no result?

Please note that I'm aware of solutions using DESCRIBE and select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='person'; 
but I need a more flexible solution that will fit these multicolumn queries.

Please also note that I am still using the original PHP MySQL extention (so no MySQLi, and no PDO).

Answer (score 9):

If you wrap your query with the following SQL, it will always return the column names from your query, even if it is an empty query result:

```
select myQuery.*
from (select 1) as ignoreMe
left join (
select * from myTable where false -- insert your query here
) as myQuery on true
```

Note: When the results of the subquery are empty, a single row of null values will be returned. If there is data in the subquery it won't affect the output because it creates a cross-product with a single row...and `value x 1 = value`

Comment: This is extremely clever as does precisely what the questioner asked, unlike the other answers here who evidently did not read the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

Execute following command if the result of your previous query is empty

```
SHOW columns FROM your-table;
```

For more details check [this.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: Why is this not voted higher? This is the fastest and cleanest way to see the columns, thank you!

Comment: Because it is not what the OP asked. He asked columns from a query, not a table,. Very different beasts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will satisfy you but you can do this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

It will return `null` values (except last column which you can ignore) if the query is empty and you will be able to access all columns. It's not proper way of doing it and selecting names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` would be much better solution.
Please note that result is aggregated and you need to use `GROUP BY` to get more results if there are any.

Comment: yeah, as you say an interesting approach, however, it has own drawback, you must use group by to preserve returned data generally

Answer (score -2):

You should ,
Select `COLUMN_NAME` From `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
Where `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdb' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';

Comment: You won;t find columns from a query there...